# Build Node app and deploy to Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I'm struggling with the building and deploying my app to the Google Cloud Functions. My cloudbuild.yaml looks like below:

```
steps:
  - name: 'node:16'
    entrypoint: 'npm'
    args:
      - install

  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: 'gcloud'
    args:
      - beta
      - functions
      - deploy
      - station-europe-north1
      - '--gen2'
      - '--region=europe-north1'
      - '--trigger-http'
      - '--runtime=nodejs16'
      - '--entry-point=runTest'
```

The problem is after the app has been deployed as the Google Cloud Function, it seems like it doesn't contain npm packages installed.

How can I fix it? I'm out of the ideas and can't find a solution.

Comment: Can you try removing the single quotes (`' '`) based on this example on [deploying to Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-functions)?

Comment: Is the node_modules directory listed in your `.gcloudignore`?

Comment: And, if your .gcloudignore doesn't exist, is your .gitignore exclude the node_module dir? If so, create a .gcloudignore, empty. And test again.